# Is it possible to have 2 activities in 1 layout in android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-tabs

I am beginner with developing in Android Studio... I created 2 tabs with 2 different activities. Both of them have the search function. So is it possible to have 2 activities in 1 layout in Android Studio?

Comment: You can use Fragments instead

Comment: what is fragments? sorry I am begginer

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two activity as activity1.java and activity2.java 
Then in activity_main create 2 fragment and pass their activity name at "android:name"
`<fragment
        android:name="com.example.activity1"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />`
`<fragment
        android:name="com.example.activity2"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use two activities with similar layout.

But as android design suggest,you should use Fragment for these types of dynamic UI layouts.

check out these tutorial for better understanding :
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html